# Compiling error LEDA 6.1

Tags: c++, c, leda

I am trying to compile the simple Hello World! program from this tutorial [LEDA Tutorial, section 1.3](http://www.leda-tutorial.org/en/unofficial/ch01s03s01.html) using LEDA 6.1 on the UNIX system of my department.

```
#include <LEDA/core/string.h>
#include <iostream>

using leda::string;
using std::cout;

int main ()
{

    string msg = "Hello World!";
    cout << msg << "\n";

}
```

After setting the environment variable

```
LEDAROOT = /usr/local/LEDA-6.1
export LEDAROOT
```

I try to compile the file `leda1.c` containing the upper code

```
g++ -c leda1.c -I$LEDAROOT/incl
```

I get some errors witch are:

```
In file included from /usr/local/LEDA-6.1/incl/LEDA/system/basic.h:70,
                 from /usr/local/LEDA-6.1/incl/LEDA/core/string.h:16,
                 from leda1.c:1:
/usr/local/LEDA-6.1/incl/LEDA/system/misc.h: In function ‘int leda::Max_Value(int&)’:
/usr/local/LEDA-6.1/incl/LEDA/system/misc.h:120: error: ‘INT_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/local/LEDA-6.1/incl/LEDA/system/misc.h: In function ‘int leda::Min_Value(int&)’:
/usr/local/LEDA-6.1/incl/LEDA/system/misc.h:121: error: ‘INT_MAX’ was not declared in this scope
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: Add  `#include <limits.h>` before `#include <LEDA/core/string.h>` and add `return 0;` into main function.

Comment: Thaaaanks!!!!!!

Comment: `return` is optional in `main`.